# The annotation processor message can not be displayed in build output window

Tags: java, android, annotations, annotation-processing

I'm writing a view-binding annotation processor demo in Android Studio. The processor is registered by using google-auto-service.

I want to test whether the processor is used or not. So I try to print some information in the `process()` method to know if it has exactly run. Here is my `process()` method detail.

```
@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.WARNING, "This is the process method in BindViewProcessor");
    return false;
}
```

This is my project structure. I have three modules. The annotation and annotation-compiler modules are the java-library module.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfg3f.png)

In the build.gradle file in the app module, I've added the processor module to make sure the processor is actually used, but it still does not work.

```
annotationProcessor project(path: ':annotation-compiler')
```

And I've used the custom annotation in my MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        @BindView(id = R.id.tv)
        String text = "Text has been changed";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you figured out a way?